# Use a variable name with spaces inline in R markdown

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

How can I include inline `R` code that refers to a variable name that contains spaces or other unusual characters (actual use-case is `Pr(>F)`)? [Backticks are the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4554977/1036500) in plain `R` script, but they don't seem to work when the code is inline in a markdown doc. Here's an example:

````
```{r}
df <- data.frame(mydata= 1:10, yourdata = 20:29)
names(df) <- c("your data", "my data")

```

The first five values of your data are `r df$`your data`[1:5]`
````

Which when knitted gives:

```
Quitting from lines 7-9 (test-main.Rmd) 
Error in base::parse(text = code, srcfile = NULL) : 
  2:0: unexpected end of input
1: df$
   ^
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> withVisible -> eval -> parse_only -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Note that this is different from [showing the backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20409172/1036500). All I want to do is have the code executed when the the doc is knitted. My workaround is to assign the value of the odd-named variable to another object with a simple name in the chunk preceding the inline code. But I'm curious about how to directly call inline these objects with unusual names.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this instance can use normal quotes,

```
 The first five values of your data are `r df$"your data"[1:5]`
```

or rather

```
 The first five values of your data are `r df[["your data"]][1:5]`
```

Comment: Thanks! As easy as that, I'm embarrassed I didn't try it in my frenzy of other methods!

Comment: presumably there are other instances (ggplot?) where this would fail; I don't think knitr's pattern matching can handle nested backticks as well as vanilla markdown, unfortunately.

Comment: @baptiste You are right. knitr cannot handle nested backticks. It will stop right after the second backtick.