# R: Referring to a variable name with special characters

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a Shiny program I'm writing, I have input variables that contain a dash, commas and brackets. Spaces I can substitute out but the rest are needed since they are refering to chemical compounds and don't make sense without them. As expected, these characters make the Shiny app unable to find the desired variable; whilst variables with none of these characters work fine.

**EDITED:** The code below is a test Shiny app. With Chemical-X(a,b) the app returns "could not find function X". With Chemical.B the app returns "object Chemical.B not found" which is the desired result since the app sees the chemical as an object and not some function that doesn't exist.

```
library (shiny)
library (ggplot2)

dat <- as.data.frame(c("Chemical-X(a,b)", "Chemical.B"))
dat[,2] <- (c(6,3)) 
colnames(dat) <- c("Chemical", "Count")

ui <- fluidPage(

 titlePanel("SE Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "varX",
              label = "Chemical",
              choices = dat[,1],
              width = "200px"),
    selectInput(inputId = "varY1",
              label = "Count",
              choices = dat[,2],
              width = "200px")
  ),
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("chemPlot")
   )
  )
 )
server <- function(input, output){

 output$chemPlot <- renderPlot({
  plot.data <- ggplot(data = dat)
    point <- plot.data + geom_point(
    aes_string(x = input$varX, y = input$varY1))
  plot(point)
  })

}
```

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Is there a known way of doing this or will I need to come up with some viable work around? I have tried using backticks as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4554977/1036500) but this hasn't worked.

Thanks, Matt

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you could supply some sample inputs and explain the desired behavior a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've fixed it now by calling as.name the Shiny input$ variable. For the example above it would look like this.

```
 server <- function(input, output){

 output$chemPlot <- renderPlot({
  plot.data <- ggplot(data = dat)
    point <- plot.data + geom_point(
    aes_string(x = as.name(input$varX), y = as.name(input$varY1)))
  plot(point)
```

This appears to work now as intended. Thank you aocall for your efforts.

Answer (score 4):

I have found that backticks and `aes_string` usually works for me.

```
library("ggplot2")
my_dodgy_var <- "name with~special character"
mtcars[[my_dodgy_var]] <- mtcars$cyl
ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x=paste0("`", my_dodgy_var, "`"), y="mpg")) + 
  geom_point()
```

I often use a helper function `paste_aes` to do this, eg:

```
paste_aes <- function(x) paste0("`", x, "`")
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to work, I think it's because I can't put " " around the input$x variable from shiny since this variable will change when the user change the page

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; could you post a small reprex?