# How to run a generalized linear mixed model (GLMM) with multiple random factors?

Tags: r, syntax, lme4

I would like to run a GLMM with multiple random factors using the function `glmer` in package `lme4`.

I have a dataset on marine debris like this:

- `count density`: numeric
- `year`: categorical, two levels
- `round`: categorical (each year has its own six rounds, so round is - nested in year)
- `monitoring site`: categorical (data is measured on each monitoring site 6 times a year, so round is crossed with monitoring site)
- `waters`: categorical (each waters has several different sites, so monitoring site is nested in waters)
- `material`: categorical

I would like to know if the count densities of marine debris is significantly different between/among years, rounds, waters and materials. So I put-in this:

```
glmm <- glmer(count density~material*(1|year/round)*(1|waters/monitoring sites),
    family=Poisson)
```

Could you please let me know if my formula is right?

And I can get nothing from the model, as I typed in:

```
glmm
```

It said:

> Error: object 'glmm' not found

So what's the right way to use `glmer`?

Comment: You must have gotten several errors.  What were they?  Some more questions/comments: (1) variables with spaces in them are problematic (at the very least they have to be protected with back-ticks); (2) it's "poisson" (lowercase), not "Poisson" (3) terms should be connected with `+` not `*`

Comment: Also note that if each `monitoring site` has its own level (its own name), then you don't need to nest within `waters`, that is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least (if your variable names really have spaces in them, which is generally a bad idea, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551424/how-to-refer-to-a-variable-name-with-spaces)) you should try:

```
glmm <- glmer(`count density` ~ material+(1|year/round)+
              (1|waters/`monitoring sites`), 
              family=poisson)
```

Also note that `year` won't work well as a random effect because it only has two levels (it's hard to estimate a variance from only two observations: see e.g. [these simulations](http://rpubs.com/bbolker/4187)), so maybe

```
glmm <- glmer(`count density` ~ material+year+(1|year:round)+
               (1|waters/`monitoring sites`), 
              family=poisson)
```

would be better.

Comment: "year won't work well as a random effect because it only has two levels" -- because?

Comment: Maybe because you'd be estimating the variance of `year` based on only 2 observations. It also makes little sense from a theoretical point of view: Years aren't drawn randomly from some larger population of years.

Comment: why the downvote? happy to try to address concerns if they are raised explicitly ...

Comment: @FransRodenburg two levels does not mean two observations.  I also disagree that it doesn't make sense (necessarily).  You could contrive a situation when it would make sense.

Comment: but two levels is the relevant value for the question of estimating the among-year variance.  @thc, I do agree that using year as a random effect could make sense.  But it is very unlikely to be practical with two years (see the simulation linked above, and the GLMM FAQ, and many discussions on r-sig-mixed-models).

Comment: I don't see why it is unpractical.  Let's say we have a strong belief that `year` variable does contribute via some physical random process -- how does nesting it with `round` improve our estimation of the random process due to `year`?  Regarding the simulation link: the s.d. is biased, but the variance is not biased.